# BLPAPI C++: How to retrieve all Securities/Symbols/Tickers from the Bloomberg (Windows) Terminal

Tags: c++, blpapi

I am retrieving Bloomberg History data based on user supplied Time Frame, and for a single instrument I am able to sucessfully retrieve History prices [Bid,Ask] by using `IntradayTickRequest` on the lines of IntradayTickExample Sample code in the SDK.

However, I am unable to find anything in the SDK through which I can retrieve all the Symbols/Tickers present in our Bloomberg Terminal.  Please let me know which functionality to use for this purpose.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to download the list of all securities covered by Bloomberg? (a) that's going to be a lot and (b) if you plan to then download data on them you will quickly reach the request limit. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to download all Securities that are being displayed/selected on our Bloomberg terminal, maybe 50 or 60 Symbols. And not all the Symbols covered by Bloomberg. I am a newcomer in this API, so I hope that I have answered your query.

Comment: The intraday requests can only be done for one security - so if you have 60 of them you need to send 60 requests. Depending on the securities, you may be able to download the list directly in your code (for example if they are part of an index).

Comment: That's exactly what I would like to know. How to download the List directly in my code. Which functionality/ functions of the API to use, in this case? Thanks

Comment: How is your list stored? Is is an index? A monitor? A CIX? A Portfolio? etc.

Comment: @assylias: I am not sure. I can only see the list in the Bloomberg Terminal window, which is there for the Visual price viewing for the dealers. So probably your answer would be a - Monitor. I am running my code in the windows machine which is hosting the same Bloomberg terminal.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with the API - you should ask support by pressing F1 twice on your terminal - they will be able to give you some guidance.

Comment: Thanks ..wil try that.

Comment: However, its very unusual because I am using the API which connects by creating an Session based on the "Localhost" and a port, which I presume is the Bloomberg instance in this particular machine. Now this instance should give me all the Selected symbols in the terminal..

Comment: No, it connects to the bbcom.exe process which is a data service - it doesn't connect to the terminal itself. There are ways to connect to the terminal (some are chargeable) but I don't use them so can't help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to download *all* symbol you see on the terminal via the Api, you always have to start with some criteria, e.g. a search string, an index to get all constituents for, etc. It would be helpful if you could clarify what do you mean by "the list", like where do you see that list? or on which function on the terminal?